# Should I open port 3000 of my server to serve NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment, server

I have an Angular + Node.JS app. When I was running the program locally I defined a `baseurl = http://localhost:3000/` in my Angular app and used this prefix for accessing to my NodeJS backend in my program defined links, but now when I wanted to deploy my app on a remote server, I changed the `baseurl`definition to the `baseurl = http://111.222.333.444:3000/`(`111.222.333.444` is my server ip address for example), but it doesn't work!

How should I connect my Angular app to the NodeServer on a remote server?

EDIT: This is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file content:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /demo/stock-front9/dist/strategy;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then

            # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not, I think is better to run the Node app with a tool like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io) and then place a reverse proxy using Nginx in front of it, PM2 will act as orchestrator over your service while Nginx will provide access only through standard web ports (80, 443).

And in the case of Angular, when compiling, it should generate a static web app which you can serve using the same Nginx reverse proxy, doing it like so you'll save yourself the effort of configuring things like CORS, API routes and so forth, everything will go through Nginx.

### Update on an example of Nginx config file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.org;

  location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version      1.1;
  }
  
  location / {
      root /path/to/angular/compiled/app;
      index index.html;
  }
 
}
```

And then the angular app should point to the same host.

Good luck and cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, but how should I edit the `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: @user3486308 Just added an example of an Nginx configuration for acting as reverse proxy and static server at the same time :)

Comment: Thank you, but should I change my Angular or NodeJS too? To add `/api/` before my routes addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You can still run your angular app locally. And for backend server, you can use proxy.
Please take a look at this.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md#using-corporate-proxy